# Handling duplicate values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ,that looks like this

```
       site  Active
0     deals  Active
1     deals  InActive
2     deals  Active
3  discount  InActive
4  discount  Active
```

i don't want to drop the duplicate items, but i want to change the Active columns value based on Site column,for example Active has to change inactive based on duplicate item in site column,Inactive also have to change based on number of duplicate items present,last duplicate item has to Active, other than that it has to be Inactive, If it is already inactive it also have to change based on that condition

Expected

```
       site    Active
0     deals  InActive
1     deals  InActive
2     deals    Active
3  discount  InActive
4  discount    Active
```

Comment: May you clarify a bit more your question, I don't seem to get it...

Comment: i edited it, i think now you can get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `duplicated()` function with `keep='last'` which will return `False` for the last duplicated value. Then simply replace `True` and `False` as per your need.

```
df1["Active"]=df1["site"].duplicated(keep='last').replace(True,"InActive").replace(False,"Active")
```